# Trying to make a function that will return longest word in a string

Tags: javascript

This what I have so far but it keeps resulting in "undefined" when I run it.

```
var sentence = 'Hello my friends';
var words = sentence.split;
var longWordLength = 0;
var longword = 'i';

function findLongWord (sentence){ 
for (a = 0; a < words.length; a++){
  if (words[a].length > longWordLength){
    longWordLength = words[a].length;
    longWord = words [a];
    return longWord}
  }
  console.log(longWord);
```

Comment: `split` is a function. `var words = sentence.split(" ")`

Comment: JS is case sensitive. `longword` !== `longWord`

Comment: You also need to `return` from outside the `for` loop: https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/9j0peqno/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) is a **function**
- You could use a RegExp expression to split by *One-or-more spaces* `/ +/`
- Keep the logic **within** your function
- JS is case sensitive, so take special care
- You could use [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
function findLongWord(sentence) {
  const words = sentence.split(/ +/);
  let longWord = '';

  words.forEach(word => {
    if (word.length > longWord.length) {
      longWord = word;
    }
  });
  
  return longWord;
}


console.log(findLongWord('Hello my friends'));   // "friends"
```

#### Example using sort:

```js
const findLongWord = (str) => str.split(/ +/).sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length)[0];

console.log(findLongWord('Hello my friends'));   // "friends"
```